# Au centre-ville ou du centre-ville?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions

> Je vais aller [prendre un verre] dans un bar du centre-ville. (Répétition disgracieuse d’une consonne ***d**ans, **d**u*).

> Je vais aller [prendre un verre] dans un bar au centre-ville.

> Je vais aller [prendre un verre] au bar d’un bistro au centre-ville. (*Au* est ici répétitif)

> Je vais aller [prendre un verre] au bar d’un bistro du centre-ville.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phrase 1/ Il n'y a pas critère véritablement objectif; peu de monde, je crois, manquera d'avoir l'opinion que trouver l'usage consécutif de « dans » et « du » disgracieux à cause de la répétion de d relève d'une oreille extrêmement exigeante et qu'en général il ne faudra pas faire attention à de telles particularités.

phrase 2/ Mis à part la répétition de « au » il n'y a pas de différence entre « au » et « du » ; « le bar est situé dans le centre » ou « le bar fait partie du centre » sont des formulations équivalentes.

phrase 3/ Je ferais une remarque un peu semblable à celle au « 1/ » pour cette répétition de  « au » ; on ne peut pas s'arrêter de trop à de telles considérations (ex : écrite à la machine à écrire, arriver à tirer à la carabine d'un seul bras, …), mais évidemment dans ce cas particulier de répétition de mot, si on a la force d'esprit d'organiser ses phrases, lorsque il existe des tournures équivalentes sans répétitions, de sorte à ne pas tolérer de « doublons », alors pourquoi ne pas le faire ? On doit considérer que le résultat est supérieur, si même seulement légèrement.

Answer (score 0):

1. On n'a pas d'impression de répétition. C'est la formule la plus naturelle; « **dans un bar du centre-ville** » forme une unité syntaxique, un complément circonstanciel unique. La phrase sous-entend aussi qu'il y a plusieurs bars au centre-ville.
2. La phrase est plus heurtée, « **au centre-ville** » n'est pas un complément du nom « **bar** » mais un deuxième complément circonstanciel d'« **aller prendre un verre** » (on peut ici intervertir les deux compléments : « je vais aller [au centre-ville] [dans un bar] »). Il n'y a peut-être qu'un seul bar au centre-ville.
3. & 4. « **Au bar d'un bistro** » est trop lourd. Même si on veut dire ici « au comptoir d'un bistro », on a une impression de répétition. Un bistro étant aussi un bar, la phrase est perçue comme signifiant « **au bar d'un bar** ».